# How do I implement the following OnClick code in my Android Studio Project?

Tags: android, android-studio

The following code  is from the Android Developers' guide to building a camera at the following URL. Please take a bit of time out to help me solve this. Best wishes!
[The aforementioned site](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera.html#capture-video)

The errors seem to be:

1. Me adding R manually before id...
2. setOnclickListener, setCaptureButtonText, View v, @Override and mMediaRecorder being shown as errors.
3. The ) at the end being highlighted as an error as well.

This is the code from the activity.xml file that shows the button being referenced:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button_capture"
    android:text="Capture"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    />
```

And the code itself below:

```
    private boolean isRecording = false;

    // Add a listener to the Capture button
    Button captureButton = (Button) findViewById(id.button_capture);
    captureButton.setOnClickListener(
    new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (isRecording) {
            // stop recording and release camera
            mMediaRecorder.stop();  // stop the recording
            releaseMediaRecorder(); // release the MediaRecorder object
            mCamera.lock();         // take camera access back from MediaRecorder

            // inform the user that recording has stopped
            setCaptureButtonText("Capture");
            isRecording = false;
        } else {
            // initialize video camera
            if (prepareVideoRecorder()) {
                // Camera is available and unlocked, MediaRecorder is prepared,
                // now you can start recording
                mMediaRecorder.start();

                // inform the user that recording has started
                setCaptureButtonText("Stop");
                isRecording = true;
            } else {
                // prepare didn't work, release the camera
                releaseMediaRecorder();
                // inform user
            }
        }
    }
    }
    );
```

Comment: they have not provided complete code in that tutorial and all those methods are not provided  there

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using XML, you really should just add the property directly to the object.  Whatever function you tell it to run will run.  No need to add any other listeners.

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button_capture"
    android:text="Capture"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:onClick="yourFunction"
    />
```

Comment: I am new to this method. How would adding the functions directly work exactly?

Comment: You are trying to call a function right now that is called "onClick".  You are doing this by wrapping it inside a listener.  I'm just saying that is unnecessary.  Whatever function (void) you want to run, just call it directly from the XML definition for the button.  Then there is no need to create a listener.

Comment: @thanksagain123 the function definition is limited if you use this way. In this case, `yourFunction` should be `public` and receive a `View v` parameter, like `public void yourFunction(View v)`. And this way can't use in Fragment because xml `android:onClick` looks up its parent or ancestor context only.